# Feeds multiple csv files

Tags: feeds, importing-exporting

I need to import products from four csv files using Feeds. Do I have to create four importers or is there a way to make one importer read four csv files? The tables are identical in each file, only products are different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two possibilities:

First, as you mentioned, use four importers, you can easily duplicate an exporter using the export/import function.

Second, Feeds includes an option in the File Fetcher plugin to 'Supply path to file or directory directly '. If you check this, you can enter the path to the directory in your site's file structure where you have uploaded your to-be-imported files and Feeds will import them at once. Just upload your files to the specified folder.